# How can I copy and paste variable in tcl into vi-editor using middle mousewheel click?

Tags: linux, unix, tcl, tk-toolkit, vi

[proc_selProc.tcl]

```
proc selProc {str offset count} {
return [string range $str $offset [expr {$offset + $count -1}]]
}

set myVar Hello
selection handle -selection . [list selproc $myVar]
selection own .
```

tool > source ./proc_selPorc.tcl

And paste it into vi-editor using middle-mousewheel click.
It worked well at first. 
[vi aa.rpt] 
Hello

However, when I try as below, I still get "Hello" not "AAA".

```
set myVar AAA 
selection handle . [list selproc $myVar] 
selection own .
```

[vi aa.rpt] 
Hello ;# <- not printed "AAA"

what should I do?
I tried many ways, but couldn't slove it.

selection clear ; selection get ; PRIMARY selectipn etc ...

Comment: The selection owner must be running and processing X11 events for it to work. Does your tool do that?

Comment: The main problem with the `PRIMARY` selection is that *many* programs scribble over it. It's meant to be whatever the user selected most recently. The `CLIPBOARD` is more robust because that's meant to only change on an explicit user-initiated Cut or Copy.

Comment: What UI are you using? I'm not going to assume X11 or a terminal or anything else. Please add that info to your question. Also, review the tags you applied, Linux is not a Unix, making those two tags mutually exclusive! Further, X11 isn't specific to either...

Comment: Yes. my tool do(X11) that. tool name is synopsys-icc2. I solved problem through the answer below. I couldn't do what i wanted using clipboard. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely it seems that the selection handler cannot be changed. Something keeps using the first command provided for a window. This looks like a bug to me. It does work if you explicitly remove the old handler first:

```
set myVar Hello
selection handle . [list selProc $myVar]
selection own .

selection handle . {}
set myVar AAA 
selection handle . [list selProc $myVar] 
selection own .
```

However, it may be better to use a different approach. Put the text you want to place on the clipboard in a global variable and have the handler pick that up:

```
proc selProc {offset count} {
    global selection
    return [string range $selection $offset [expr {$offset + $count -1}]]
}

set selection Hello
selection handle . selProc
selection own .
# Middle-click pastes "Hello"
set selection AAA
selection own .
# Middle click pastes "AAA"
```

Update: This is a bug. When a handler for the STRING type is installed, a copy of the handler is installed for the UTF8_STRING type. However, when the handler is changed, only the STRING version is updated. The UTF8_STRING version is left alone. Presumably that's the one picked up by the middle mouse-click.

Knowing this, another solution could be to specify the `-type UTF8_STRING` option:

```
set myVar Hello
selection handle -type UTF8_STRING . [list selProc $myVar]

set myVar AAA 
selection handle -type UTF8_STRING . [list selProc $myVar]
```

I have created a [bug report](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview/af31a84c91) for this issue.

Comment: That would be odd if it was true, and unlike how Tk normally works...

Comment: It surprised me too. But I can readily reproduce it. I'll look into it and open a bug, if my current understanding is true.

Comment: The Tk sources say that the handlers are chained in a linked list, so that  one can add several handlers, e.g. for different selection types. The manual fails to mention that, so perhaps it's a bug in the manual.

Comment: I see. But having multiple handlers for the same selection and type seems to cause unpredictable behavior. Tcl/Tk itself uses the last handler when running `selection get`, but some external programs apparently pick the first one.

Comment: Amazing. The problem was solved perfectly using "selection handle . {}" .  I think that I didn't explain my environment enough. My tool name is icc2 in Synopsys. I work on with multiple icc2-gui. I wanted to quickly copy and paste string variable from the tool. It's completely resolved, allow me to do work faster. Thank you for reply.